# Ember component unit testing inject service defined in initalizer

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, dependency-injection, ember-qunit, ember-testing

I am writing a unit test case for my component.

Ember 0.12,
Ember-qunit 0.3.13
Ember-i18n: "4.1.1",

I am initialising this i18n service in via `Ember initaliazers`, so that i can access i18n serivces as `this.i18n.t('some key')`. which i am using in my component

```
some: computed('', {
 get(){
   this.i18n.t('somekey') + "Test"
 }
})
```

My component unit test for this component fails, because i am not able to inject the i18n service. Please help me in solving it and i tried

`needs: ['serivces:i18n']` it wont work because i have initialised via **Intializers**  [Issue injecting via initalizer](https://github.com/switchfly/ember-test-helpers/pull/113)

and the below code also wont work because i am using older version of ember-qunit (Please i don't wont to update to newest version because it affects all other test cases)

```
 this.register('service:user-session', userSession);
 this.inject.service('user-session', { as: 'userSession' });
```

Help me in solving in this issue , if there is a need for more clarity in the question , please do comment. Thanks

Comment: Can you try this: `Ember.getOwner(subject).register('service:user-session', userSession);` Subject can be retrieved by `this.subject()` while using in unit tests.